# How do I use SXD-XPath to iterate over a nodeset and print out every value?

Tags: xpath, rust

I’ve been trying to query XML with the [sxd-xpath crate](https://crates.io/crates/sxd-xpath) and I can’t seem to figure out how to handle a nodeset.

Crate and using

```
extern crate sxd_document;
extern crate sxd_xpath;

use sxd_document::parser;
use sxd_xpath::{Factory, Context, Value};
```

Actual code

```
let package = parser::parse("<feed><title>hest</title><title>hest2</title><title>hest3</title><title>hest4</title></feed>").expect("failed to parse XML");
let document = package.as_document();

let factory = Factory::new();
let xpath = factory.build("/feed/title").expect("Could not compile XPath");
let xpath = xpath.expect("No XPath was compiled");

let context = Context::new();

let value = xpath.evaluate(&context, document.root()).expect("XPath evaluation failed");
```

I would like to iterate over every node and print out the value of `<title>`, but I do not understand how to do it.

I’m fairly new in the Rust world, coming from C# and Python.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`XPath::evaluate`](https://docs.rs/sxd-xpath/0.4.1/sxd_xpath/struct.XPath.html#method.evaluate) returns a `Value`:

```
fn evaluate<'d, N>(
    &self,
    context: &Context<'d>,
    node: N,
) -> Result<Value<'d>, ExecutionError>
where
    N: Into<Node<'d>>,
```

A [`Value`](https://docs.rs/sxd-xpath/0.4.1/sxd_xpath/enum.Value.html) is an enumeration of the possible values of an XPath (a number, a boolean, a string, or a nodeset). In your case, you are interested in a nodeset, so you will want to match on that variant:

```
if let Value::Nodeset(nodes) = value {
    // ...
}
```

[`Nodeset`](https://docs.rs/sxd-xpath/0.4.1/sxd_xpath/nodeset/struct.Nodeset.html) implements `IntoIterator`, so you can use it in a `for` loop:

```
for node in nodes {
    // ...
}
```

Each yielded value will be a [`Node`](https://docs.rs/sxd-xpath/0.4.1/sxd_xpath/nodeset/enum.Node.html). This is an enumeration of all the different types of nodes in an XML document. You are interested in `Element`s. If *all* you care about is the string value of the element, you can use [`Node::string_value`](https://docs.rs/sxd-xpath/0.4.1/sxd_xpath/nodeset/enum.Node.html#method.string_value). This hides away any complexities of multiple child nodes each with their own text:

```
println!("{}", node.string_value());
```

Put all together:

```
if let Value::Nodeset(nodes) = value {
    for node in nodes {
        println!("{}", node.string_value());
    }
}
```

A `Nodeset` doesn't have a guaranteed order, so if you want the nodes in the order that they come from in the document, you can call [`Nodeset::document_order`](https://docs.rs/sxd-xpath/0.4.1/sxd_xpath/nodeset/struct.Nodeset.html#method.document_order):

```
if let Value::Nodeset(nodes) = value {
    for node in nodes.document_order() {
        println!("{}", node.string_value());
    }
}
```

**Disclaimer**: I am the author of SXD-Document and SXD-XPath

Comment: That helped and thanks for the elaborated answer. Nice touch with `doucment_order`, but the order of elements in my case is less important.